# How to create a segue to slide in and fade in at the same time (Xcode 9, Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm trying to create a custom segue which slides in from the right and slides out (like the default Push segue) but also fades in/out as it slides in/out. I think I've figured out the fading code for transitioning to the destination view controller but can't figure out how to make the view slide in from the left and slide out to the right. I thought this would have something to do with the trailing and leading constraints of the view but I'm not really sure how to reference those constraints in my custom segue class. I know you can connect constraints to the code using IBOutlets for specific view controllers but I want to use this same custom segue class for custom segues across all my view controllers.

I was also wondering how to make the segue refer to the unwind segue class to go from the destination view controller to the source view controller. For example, when I click on the segue in the storyboard, in the "class" text field, I put the class name for the segue which transitions to the destination view controller but where would I do the same for the unwind segue so that when I click back, it also performs the custom segue to go back to the source view controller.

This is the code I've done so far for the segue which transitions to the destination view controller (haven't started on the unwind segue yet but I imagine it would be pretty much the same). Near the bottom of the class, I started trying out the anchor properties but they didn't work. Thanks!

```
class DimSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        // Get the view of the source
        let sourceViewControllerView = self.source.view
        // Get the view of the destination
        let destinationViewControllerView = self.destination.view

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        // Make the destination view the size of the screen
        destinationViewControllerView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)

        // Insert destination below the source
        // Without this line the animation works but the transition is not smooth as it jumps from white to the new view controller
        destinationViewControllerView?.alpha = 0;
        sourceViewControllerView?.addSubview(destinationViewControllerView!);

        let margins = destinationViewControllerView?.superview?.layoutMarginsGuide

        // Animate the fade, remove the destination view on completion and present the full view controller
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {

            destinationViewControllerView?.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (margins?.leadingAnchor)!, constant: 1000)

            destinationViewControllerView?.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (margins?.trailingAnchor)!, constant: 1000)

            destinationViewControllerView?.layoutIfNeeded()

            destinationViewControllerView?.alpha = 1

        }, completion: nil )


    }
}
```

Comment: It's better to post code as code(not as image), as this makes it easier for answerers to reference it.

Comment: oh ok I see thanks